# Spring Security Oauth2 login with token based session

Tags: spring, security, token, spring-security-oauth2, jsessionid

I've been reading op on several Oauth2 guides and tutorials to figure out how to setup a Oauth2 security flow using Spring security (version 5.x). The flow itself is working correctly and I'm ending up with a JESSION cookie on my frontend application (Angular).

However, instead of using a jsessionid, I would like to use a token to authenticate with my backend. I've experimented a bit with sending my access token as bearer token but my SecurityContext remains emty. The only time when I actually get some values in my SecurityContext is when I pass the jsessionid as cookie in my request.

Is this a setting that can be toggled in Spring Security or do I need to write some custom code to pull this of?

Comment: Do you actually need that? The reason it's a cookie is because that's the most secure and also the simplest option.

Comment: To start with, do you have sessions disabled? 
see example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504590/how-can-i-use-spring-security-without-sessions

Comment: Have you checked this? [Spring REST API + OAuth2 + Angular](https://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-spring-oauth2-angular)