# spring boot oauth2 resource server is not stateless

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, keycloak

So I've been trying to create a stateless resource server using oauth2.
I created empty spring boot app with only two dependencies `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web` and `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server`. Then I created docker-compose file with keycloak so that I would have some out of the box solution for authentication. After theat I configured my realm and added one property to `application.yml`:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: http://localhost:40000/auth/realms/myrealm
```

After that I configured Postman to get token from keycloak before accessing my application. And all works like a charm, but tere is one tiny problem that bugs me. So when I call my application for the first time it returs `401` when I won't send the token and that is so cool, then I send request with token and it respondes with code `200` and that is also very cool. The problem is that when I send 3rd request without token I still get `200`. Now I think the issue is `JSESSIONID`, since when I remove it I get `401` again. How can I make my application truly stateless? I would like my app to require token with every request. Also why this stateless behaviour is not default with oauth2?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use Spring Security without sessions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504590/how-can-i-use-spring-security-without-sessions)

Comment: Thank you, it fixes my problem, but does not answer why it is not default behaviour for oauth2 resource server? Also where can I found default implementation of WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter that is used if I won't provide one in my configuration?

Comment: #default_behavior: you name it - it is a *web* security adapter?  #default_impl: [open source](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/main/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java)! L. 221f is the default config